# Running a timesten query on a remote server inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to run a timesten sql query on a remote server from my local machine. The query is inside a script, I am able to connect to the db but the problem is with the query field.

This is my script 
runttquery.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=$1
ssh dba@rhost << "EOF"
ttIsql "dsn=rhostdsn";
select * from table1 where id='$cmd';
EOF
```

When I run the above script by passing an argument  "testid",
`./runttquery.sh testid`

the $cmd in the sql query isn't getting replaced with the "testid" argument that I passed and I get 0 results from the remote server.

I just need to replace the id value in my sql query with the argument that I passed to the script.

Comment: You have to escape the single quoutes around $cmd, else it is interpreted as literal "$cmd" and not a variable.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thanks! for the response, I tried the script again, this time I escaped the single quotes but still got the same result.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the variable with whatever value was passed to the script in the sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrectly substituting the variable $cmd, I removed the quotes around EOF(heredoc limitstring) and add {} around $cmd. The following works perfectly fine now.

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=$1
ssh dba@rhost << EOF
ttIsql "dsn=rhostdsn";
select * from table1 where id='${cmd}';
EOF
```